# Phased transactions are very slow

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, nxt, voting

I am trying to send a message to another account with two confirmations using the Phasing options in a message to add two different accounts. The problem is the message takes from 1 minute to 2 minutes to be sent. On the other hand when one of the users tries to approve the transaction also takes from 2 minutes till 5 minutes sometimes or more, and very rare it's quicker.

I have tried these operations using the local NXT with Testnet: locahost:6876, and the online Tool using the following URL: demo.jelurida.com.

Is there another way to do this quickly? I have read about Ardor too do you think it's a better choice?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

By default it takes roughly 1 minute to send a transaction and once that is confirmed, it requires the 2nd party to make an approval transaction so thats another 1 minute. so roughly 2+ minutes which is what you have. Ardor would have the same timing aswell. Your stuck with the roughly 1 minute confirmations.